# How to letter space TextView to match parent?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-design-library

I am trying to design a Credit Card view in Android and need to space the letters so that they fill the width of the screen. They need to do this dynamically as screensizes are variable so I can't just set a TextSize.

The textview below is currently what I have and set to match_parent

[image]

I need it to be spaced out like this:

[image]

Comment: Use this library. https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview

Comment: Will you be using a single text view?

Comment: If you're not going to use the library, you can use 4 textviews.

Comment: I would prefer to use a single TextView